# Toggle issue using input value as id

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to use jQuery's `.toggle()` to show and hide one of three divs. The divs have unique ids and the decision which div is got toggled is based on which of the three radio buttons has been selected. The three radio buttons have values that correspond to the ids of the divs. So if someone clicks the -1 radio, the div with the id `cMB_0292_A07.m1` should be toggled.

However I'm not getting any response at all and there's no report of any errors in debugger that I've tried. What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function showdiv(obj) {
            var n = obj.name;
            var v = $("input:radio[name='" + n + "']:checked").val();
            alert(v);
            $("#" + v).toggle();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="cMB_0292_A07" value="cMB_0292_A07.m1" onclick="showdiv(this);" type="radio">-1
    <input name="cMB_0292_A07" value="cMB_0292_A07.0" onclick="showdiv(this);" type="radio">0
    <input name="cMB_0292_A07" value="cMB_0292_A07.p1" onclick="showdiv(this);" type="radio">+1
    <div id="cMB_0292_A07.m1" style="display: none">minus1</div>
    <div id="cMB_0292_A07.0" style="display: none">zero</div>
    <div id="cMB_0292_A07.p1" style="display: none">plus1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a **two part issue**

First off, you *shouldn't* have `.` within IDs.

Secondly, jQuery is seeing this: `$('#ID.CLASS')`
It is searching the DOM looking for ID: `cMB_0292_A07`then a child class of `m1` for example.

You can fix this, by either removing the periods within your IDs, or using the regex selector `[id=""]`.

```
 $('[id="' + v + '"]').toggle();
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/708v0qw3/)**

---

Other sidenotes, don't use `onClick` events. It's better to separate your business logic & presentation logic. Use jQuery `.on('click', function () {});` events!

Comment: Not only inline JS `onclick` is outdated, `var n = obj.name; var v = $("input:radio[name='" + n + "']:checked").val();` is redundant code (instead of simple `var v = obj.value;`).

Comment: I spent four hours trying to figure this out. Of course!!! The ids were generated from file name, which is why they had . in them. Thank you immensely @mcpDESIGNS

Comment: Thanks @Regent I've altered this now. Incidentally, what should be used in place of `onclick`?

Comment: Give those radio buttons a `class`. And create a click event (within your document.ready) `$('.yourRadioButtonsClass').on('click', function () { /* code here */ });`

Comment: Thanks again @mcpDESIGNS I'll work on implementing that. I don't use jQuery very often but maybe I should invest a bit of time getting to grips with it. Thanks to all for your time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.`, since it will look for its child with class `m1` or `0` or `p1`.

Check out below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        alert($("#"+$(this).val()).length);
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="cMB_0292_A07" value="cMB_0292_A07" type="radio">-1
<input name="cMB_0292_A07" value="cMB_0292_A07" type="radio">0
<input name="cMB_0292_A07" value="cMB_0292_A07" type="radio">+1
<div id="cMB_0292_A07" style="display: none">minus1</div>
<div id="cMB_0292_A07" style="display: none">zero</div>
<div id="cMB_0292_A07" style="display: none">plus1</div>
```